# Java String Index Out Of Bounds Exception: String index out of range - on non empty line

Tags: java, exception, readline

Reading text file into string, extracting data, adding data into text pane.
Problem is exception appearing on non empty line. Only one same line in every page.

Problem is that the string is populated but not shown in text pane or successfully mined because of exception. I can verify that by printing it out. Here is output window and code.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -32
P/n: 4B6199907-1 S/n: VBABC0080104 Zone: FIN:
```

Similar line is further in text and it is not being skipped.
File is pdf export to txt file. If i use some pdf to txt converter, more lines are corrupted. If i copy paste the report to another file problem persists. If i copy paste the line in another file, problem is not appearing.
Dont understand why the string is there as shown in output but returns exception when processed by doc.insertString or other string functions.

```
StyledDocument doc = jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
try {
    TempLine=s.nextLine();
    DataMine(TempLine);
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), TempLine+ "\n", null);
}catch(Exception e) { 
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(TempLine);
}
```

Any help appreciated. BTW: This is not a repeat question because all other string out of range problems relate to empty lines and people experience them throughout file.

Comment: How do you process the string data ? Do you use charAt() ? The quite typical root cause is that the index value in charAt() is out of range. Have you made the run with the trace and debugging in IDE ?

Comment: The exception may have occurred inside `DataMine(TempLine)`, try using `e.printStackTrace();` inside the catch block to get more details of the error.

Comment: You are right, about where is the problem and now i'm even more confused. I cahnged order of and put DataMine behind doc.insertString and now i see the string in jTextPane. I dont understand why my function corrupts the string. It is passed into function but not edited. I use .contains; . indexof; .substring; but i dont edit the TempString in any way.

Comment: You used `substring()` method and it can return OutOfBoundException [String#substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Ok, thanks. problem solved by checking if a,b of substing are positive before running substring. But i dont understand why is the original string that i use to get substring corrupted after use, and won't display in text pane.

Comment: Check again the spec. It throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Comment: Ok, will handle exception correctly. Thanks